# Are eevee volumetrics always going to be confined to square shapes?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

Far as I can tell eevee will always render any shape with a volumetric material applied as a cube or rectangle, as opposed to say a sphere or something a bit more complex.
Is this a hard limitation? Or something that might change later.

Comment: I don't think it is a hard limitation, you can render smoke with eevee with complex geometry.

Comment: Read: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/limitations.html